# I want every single details from the i upload .. using attachment_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want every single details from the file i upload.. i am using attachment_fu, and i want to know that when the image is been taken , what is ISO , and  which model of camera were used ,, ,,  In short i want all the detailed property of image  ,, Is it possible ? how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you are looking is metadata called "Exif" (Exchangeable image file format), and is found in jpeg and tiff images. You can't find this in png or gif files.

There is an Exif gem that reads this metadata. You can find it (and its documentation) [here](http://exifr.rubyforge.org/).

The tricky part may be to get it to work together with attachment_fu. The easiest way to do this is most likely to create a callback in your model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_attachment
  after_attachment_saved do |record|
     # do your exif stuff here using the Exif gem         
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thank s buddy , ur answer is usefull to me ,, i got it late but ur answer is perfact  .We can use Rmagick for the use of EXIF too.

Answer (score 1):

```
  @upload.save        

    image = Magick::ImageList.new("public/"+ @upload.public_filename)        
    @upload.date_taken = DateTime.strptime(image.get_exif_by_entry('DateTime')[0][1], "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
    @upload.model  = image.get_exif_by_entry('model')[0][1]
    @upload.camera  = image.get_exif_by_entry('make')[0][1]
    @upload.iso  =  image.get_exif_by_entry('ISOSpeedRatings')[0][1]
    @upload.update_attributes(params[:@upload])
```

After saving any upload by rmaiggic and Exif we can get  all the MEta data ..  we can add all the details  ,, and fro that on the top of the controller one has to write

require 'RMagick'

install gem name EXIF  :: gem install exif
image.get_exif_by_entry() will give all the functions available
Thanks every one to help me 
Arpit